# use xml config file for variables in ssis

Tags: xml, ssis

I am using xml config file for 2 variables. I created it and changed accordingly. But its not running the package and giving me an error 
 **"Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsRuntimeException: The element cannot be found in a collection. This error happens when you try to retrieve an element from a collection on a container during execution of the package and the element is not there."**

my xml file is as below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

- 
- 
   
  
- 
   
  
- 
  0 
  
- 
   
  
- 
  0 
  
- 
  InputDirectory 
  
- 
  User 
  
- 
  0 
  
- 
  0 
  
- 
  h:\My Documents\Files to use in SSIS\Inputs\Intraday\OPTION_DAILY_INTRADAY_ASIA20140212.gz 
  
- 
   
  
- 
  0 
  
- 
   
  
- 
  0 
  
- 
  outPutDirectory 
  
- 
  User 
  
- 
  0 
  
- 
  0 
  
- 
  h:\My Documents\Files to use in SSIS\Inputs\Intraday\OPTION_DAILY_INTRADAY_ASIA20140212.gz

here i am using 2 variables which will be used in script task.

Comment: Have you added the variables to the Read/Write variables in the script task so it can pick it up? Make sure the variables are correct I believe they are case sensitive as well. Are you mapping from the XML file to the value property of the variable?

Comment: Yeah this was the mistake. I always do this..

Answer (score 1):

Solved problem.
Actually it was the mistake that i didn't include the varible in read/write for Script task.
Silly mistake but very important. And i always do this.